# Counting in binary

Tags: javascript

I'm only learning to program and was trying to make a program to count in binary.

I made a function that could convert the provided decimal to binary and it looks to be working just ok, but when I try to count upwards using a for loop my browser freezes and I can't understand why. Using a similar while loop produces the result I needed.

The problem is right at the bottom commented out. Please help figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's my code:

```
function isOdd(num) {return num % 2};

var toBinary = function (number) {
 ints = [];
 binary = [];
 ints.push(Math.floor(number));

 while (number >= 1) {
     number = (Math.floor(number))/2;
     ints.push(Math.floor(number));
 }

 for (i=ints.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
     if (isOdd(ints[i])) {
         binary.push(1);
     } else {
         binary.push(0);
     }
 }

 if (binary[0] === 0) {
     binary.splice(0,1);
 }

 return binary;

};

var count = 0;
while (count <= 50) {
 console.log(toBinary(count));
 count++;
}

/*
for (i=1;i<=50;i++) {
 console.log(toBinary(i));
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for (var i=ints.length-1;i>=0;i--)` and `for (var i=1;i<=50;i++)`, otherwise `i` will be a global variable and it will be overwritten inside `toBinary`.

Comment: To be honest I couldn't understand your answer at first, but then I noticed you could use var in the loop syntax. I have tried and it is working as intended, thank you very much! But personally I have noticed that if I just changed the variable name of my counting loop to something else than i the counting works much faster.

Comment: But just changing the variable names does not solve the real problem. The problem is, that you are defining `i` and the global scope and you are not aware on what this causes inside other scopes. As you are currently learning programming I would strongly recommend you to have a look at a tutorial about Javascript scopes.

Comment: So what I did isn't the right thing. I'm going to read more about scope then, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `i` in the `toBinary` function, hence `i` is redefined on every call of `toBinary` in the last loop, and  `i` will never reach 50.

Use `var` to declare variables like so:

```
var toBinary = function (number) {    
   var ints = [],
       binary = [],
       i;
    :
}
```

Comment: So that was causing my browser to freeze! Thanks for help! Now I wonder if I used another variable(not i) in my counting loop would it work...

Comment: @TarasDzyadevich Yes, it would also work. However, you should use as few global variables as possible, and even globals should be declared with `var` too. As user1983983 suggested, you can read more about function s and function scope at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).